# How to custom React-Konva rotation handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I've started [react-konva](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva).
And I am trying to use [`Transfomer`](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/react/Transformer.html).

For now `rotate` handler is top-center and I want to place it to `bottom-center` with `rotateHandlerOffset`.
I have updated `back` shape using `sceneFunc`. And set `y` position as following

```
this.transformer.find('.rotater').y(shape.height() + this.transformer.rotateHandlerOffset());
```

The problem is it doesn't work.

Please check on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xv4318pp0o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setAttrs` to set `attrs` like `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.

```
this.transformer.findOne('.rotater').setAttrs({
    y: shape.height() + this.transformer.rotateHandlerOffset()
});
```

Comment: It's working. But another question. When rotating it's `.back` is not drawing as `sceneFunc`. How can I handle this?

Comment: I am also getting that issue. And I have checked `konvajs` and they are drawing `.back` not based on `sceneFunc`. I think it's better to contact Konva team.